# Find the general solution to non homogeneous linear equation

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

The question:
State the general solutuon of:
$$5x_1-2x_2+4x_3=5$$

My attempt: I tried following closely an example provided for homogeneous equations without any luck:

$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}2x_2-4x_3+5\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
x_2\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
+x_3\begin{bmatrix}-4\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}5\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

And after this step I get stuck since I don't know whether is correct and should proceed with the solution space (and also how to find the solution space for non homogenous equations)

As for who might be concerned, the question is homework related.

It would be nice to know why I got downvoted so I can improve my question

Based on the feedback received from @Isham the system should have been written as follows:

$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}5x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}2x_2-4x_3+5\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}2/5x_2-4/5x_3+1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
x_2\begin{bmatrix}2/5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
+x_3\begin{bmatrix}-4/5\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: what are exactly  $x_1 x_2$  and $x_3 $ ?

Comment: @Isham are the unknowns of the system

Comment: @Isham, can you explain please why the last one is 5 0 0? should I pick the other two equations as equal to 0 instead of 1?

Comment: because you only had 5 in the first line and no number in the second and third line so must be 0 and youy should correct $5x_1−2x_2+4x_3=5⟺x_1=1+x_22/5-x_34/5 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your equation Lucian, it should be rather this:

$x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}2/5x_2-4/5x_3+1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
x_2\begin{bmatrix}2/5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}
+x_3\begin{bmatrix}-4/5\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the pattern:

For
$$5x_1-2x_2+4x_3=5$$
then $x_{3} = \frac{1}{4} \, (5 - 5 \, x_{1} + 2 \, x_{2})$
and
\begin{align}
x &=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_2 \\ \frac{1}{4} \, (5 - 5 \, x_{1} + 2 \, x_{2}) \end{bmatrix}
= \frac{1}{4} \, \begin{bmatrix} x_{1} \\ x_2 \\ 5 - 5 \, x_{1} + 2 \, x_{2} \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \frac{x_1}{4} \, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -5 \end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{x_2}{4} \, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{5}{4} \, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: Hi @Leucippus, is there a reason why you’ve decided to use $$x_3$$ as a dependent variable?

Comment: no, it was just his choice, you can choose whichever one you want.